# How to pass posts_per_page and paged params query vars to custom taxonomy archive urls?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination, archives, 404-error

So I made some custom posts and taxonomies..

`http://example.com/?product_category=mytaxonomyterm&lang=it`

Till here, all fine: I get a 'mytaxonomyterm' taxonomy archive. Btw, lang is because I'm using polylang plugin.

If I try to add `&posts_per_page=15` to url, it doesn't work: it won't change number of post.

Even worse, if I add `paged=1`, It will reload into 
`http://example.com/?product_category=mytaxonomyterm&lang=it` (so stripping the page param).

Even worse, if I add `paged=1`, it will throw an error telling me that there's an error in post-template.php on line 279, 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

So what? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding" those parameters? Are you editing the string in the browser address bar? Or trying to construct links in the PHP?

Comment: To try, I'm just adding to the browser. But what's the point with my question? The problem is the results, not where you write the query. I guess. Thank you.

Comment: What matters, first, is whether you are generating the correct string, so, yes, how you are doing it is important.

Answer (score 2):

> If I try to add `&posts_per_page=15` to url, it doesn't work: it won't change number of post.

I wonder if you're looking for a custom query variable, e.g. `ppp`, to change the number of posts for the main query:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars )
{
  $vars[] = "ppp";
  return $vars;
} );

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() )
    {
        $ppp = $q->get( 'ppp' );
        if( ! empty( $ppp ) && 20 >= (int) $ppp )
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', (int) $ppp );
    }
} );
```

where we limit the maximum number of posts to 20. You could then restrict this further if needed.

> What am I doing wrong?

The `posts_per_page` is a **private** query variable in the `WP` class, so you will not be able to use it as a GET parameter in your request, to modify the main query.

The `paged` is a **public** query variable, so you can access that one.

Comment: +1 for the posts_per_page being private :), I didn't notice. Anyway, as you wrote, paged is public so should't I be able to pass it on the url? es &paged=2? It currently doesn't work (and yes, I created enough posts for 3+ pages).

Comment: Did you try it out on the default theme? Maybe the error issue with paged is theme or plugin related? Do you have permalinks off ? @Stratboy

Comment: Since I'm currently speaking of custom taxonomies, I cannot use the default theme. I'm using mine (I don't use thirdy parts things), but it's really bare bones for now. Permalinks are temporarily off, but I had same results even with perma-on. Basically, when adding paged=2, the dispatcher will route to a wrong template and will not populate variables. The error is coming out of post-template.php, searching for $post->post_content, but $post is NULL, hence the non-object error. It should be an archive, though.. Just like it currently IS without the paged var.

Comment: Update: I found out in fact it goes to a 404, and the $post error was correct since I had called the_content() inside the 404 template. Still I can't figure out WHY it ends up on a 404 as soon as I add a paged variable.

Comment: ok, it suddenly started to work.. Don't know... getting mad.

Comment: strange, but good to hear it works, maybe your WordPress just needs a hug ;-)  @Stratboy