# Alter Woocommerce posts per page attribute

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, parameter

I need to alter the **post_per_page** value of the displayed products.

In your opinion is possible to achieve this using a param added to the url? Something like www.siteurl.com/shop/?post_per_page=xx

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: the post_per_page value will be dynamic or static ??

Comment: Static. I think I'm incurring in the same problem of this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213064/how-to-pass-posts-per-page-and-paged-params-query-vars-to-custom-taxonomy-archiv. I don't see a valid solution...

Comment: There is a valid solution as an answer to that question. Did you try it?

Comment: The linked answer is exactly what you are looking for.